# close an activity after some time

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make a dice rolling app and I want to run an activity which displays an image of the result when a button is pressed and close it after a few seconds. So how can I do this?

Maybe there's another way to display an image on top of my activity without calling a new activity? I'm not sure.

I've read some things about timers but I don't really get it. And I know people will tell me to let the user tap to dismiss the window but for this app I'm sure I want it gone automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this:

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
 t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // If you want to call Activity then call from here for 5 seconds it automatically call and your image disappear....
        }
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: But where should I put this in my activity? It has to be outside onCreate right?

Comment: after onCreate so whenever your Activity start then timer will be executed.

Comment: I got it! I called finish() where you hace your comment. Is that ok?

Comment: yes exactly what i want to say you...

Answer (score 3):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                }, 1500);
```

Comment: seems like you are doing almost the same thing Piyush said but with a handler instead of a timer. How is that different?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to this.

You can have a ImageView which is Gone/Invisible and later when you want to show it you can turn on the visibility to View.Visible.

You can have a timer. Check [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and when the timer expires, you can do the needed with the ImageView. I feel, you need to add additional overload with another activity.

Comment: How can I run a time after onCreate() without taking any input? That's what I cant understand with all those timer examples...

Answer (score 0):

`Maybe there's another way to display an image on top of my activity without calling a new activity? I'm not sure.`

I think you can also use dialog to display image.

`I want to run an activity which displays an image of the result when a button is pressed and close it after a few seconds. So how can I do this?`

use CountDownTime [Example](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-count-down-timer.html). and in button click.

```
  mTimer = new MyTimer(timeToDisplay, interval);
  mTimer.start()
```

Sample code..

```
 class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

     //constructor for timer class
    public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }


   // this method called when timer is finished
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        //close activity or dismiss dialog here 
    }

     //this method is called for every iteration of time interval
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


    }

}
```

Comment: But I don't want any button clicked. or do you mean I run the timer in the first activity?

Comment: use this `mTimer = new MyTimer(timeToDisplay, interval);
  mTimer.start()` whenever you want to start timer(display image).

Answer (score 0):

try this its work after button click and the activity will finished after 2 sec

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        finish();

                    }
                }, 2000);

            }
        });
```